# Google scipts - cannot convert array to object[][]

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pull some information off poloniex.com and paste into a range in a google sheet and am running into issues when trying to set the values. I am pretty new at this and cannot tell if the issue is with my understanding of how setValues works or if it has to do with the way I'm pushing data into my prices array.

```
function processPoloAPI() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<insert sheet id here>')
  var APIPullSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("APIPull");
  APIPullSheet.getRange('A2:D19999').clearContent();

  var url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_BTC&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=86400"
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  var prices = new Array ();
  prices.push(['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open','Close', 'Volume', 'QuoteVolume', 'WeightedAverage'])

  for(var key in parcedData)
   {
     prices.push(parcedData[key]);
   }

  var length = prices.length
  askRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, length, 8);
  askRange.setValues(prices);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following modification?

#### Modification points :

1. Data for `setValues()` is 2 dimensional array.
2. When it retrieves values using keys from JSON, the upper/lower cases for keys should be matched to JSON data.
3. In your script, `prices` is `[[Date, High, Low, Open, Close, Volume, QuoteVolume, WeightedAverage], {date=1424304000, volume=46.27631267, high=244, low=225, weightedAverage=239.62777823, quoteVolume=0.19311748, close=244, open=225},,,`. If you want to create data that each row only numbers for the keys at the top row, each number has to be retrieved from JSON data.

The modified script which was reflected in these modification points is as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
function processPoloAPI() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<insert sheet id here>')
  var APIPullSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("APIPull");
  APIPullSheet.getRange('A2:D19999').clearContent();

  var url = "https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=USDT_BTC&start=1405699200&end=9999999999&period=86400"
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  var prices = new Array ();
  prices.push(['Date', 'High', 'Low', 'Open','Close', 'Volume', 'QuoteVolume', 'WeightedAverage'])

  var keys = ['date', 'high', 'low', 'open', 'close', 'volume', 'quoteVolume', 'weightedAverage'];
  for (var i in parcedData) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var j in keys) {
       temp.push(parcedData[i][keys[j]]);
    }
    prices.push(temp);
  }

  var length = prices.length
  askRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, length, 8);
  askRange.setValues(prices);
}
```

#### Result :

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Rob Yocum Welcome. Thank you, too.